# How to get items from a Sharepoint Online list using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

I'm writing a PowerShell script that connects to a SharePoint website and I'm trying to get the items on a list. Here's my code:

```
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)

$SitePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $SitePwd -AsPlainText -Force
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($SiteUser,$SitePassword)
$Context.Credentials = $Creds

$web = $Context.Web 
$Context.Load($web)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

$List = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle('Déposes')
$Context.Load($List)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

But now I'm stuck with this `$List` Object and I can't find a way through. For now, I just want to display my list's items.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve list items using the SharePoint CSOM API in PowerShell:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")


Function Get-SPOContext([string]$Url,[string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
    $context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
    return $context
}

Function Get-ListItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [String]$ListTitle) {
    $list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)
    $qry = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery()
    $items = $list.GetItems($qry)
    $Context.Load($items)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
    return $items 
}



$UserName = "jdoe@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
$Password = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the password"    
$Url = "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/"


$context = Get-SPOContext -Url $Url -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
$items = Get-ListItems -Context $context -ListTitle "Tasks" 
foreach($item in $items)
{
   #...
}
$context.Dispose()
```

Comment: i think the is no need to dispose the context, because SharePoint Management Shell is using the Webservices and not the Server Object Model

Comment: will this code work? I tried to print all the items in the "foreach" loop like this:
foreach($item in $items)
{
    Write-Host ($item | Format-Table | Out-String)
}

there are errors:
Format-Table : The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

It looks the list item is not initialized.

Comment: @caolei Some of the properties will give you an error if you try retrieving them so you cannot generically display items (or any SharePoint objects tbh) without knowing what you want to grab. A good starting place is by using `$item.FieldValues` instead.

Comment: @Daniel That's correct; when you close PowerShell it will free the memory so if this is a one-time run, there's no need to call `Dispose()`. However if this is running in a loop or in a high-load environment where memory is really in demand, it can be useful to call it, and it's also a good habit to get into for all your code (freeing memory when you're done with it should be standard practice wherever practical).